# Foreach loop using CefSharp not moving to next site

Tags: c#, cefsharp

What i'm trying to do here is to loop a few websites and have the page displayed in the `CefSharp` browser.

**Code:**

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace rankjester
{
    public partial class FormBrowser : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        private readonly FormMain _formMain;
        readonly string[] listOfSites;

        public FormBrowser(string[] sitesList, FormMain formMain)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _formMain = formMain;
            //InitChromeBrowser(sitesList);
            listOfSites = sitesList;
        }

        public string InitChromeBrowser(string site)
        {
            var complete = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                // Init CEF.
                CefSettings settings = new CefSettings
                {
                    CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), @"cache\")

                };

                Cef.Initialize(settings);
                browserMain.Text = "BROWSER - [ " + @"https://www." + site + " ] ";
                browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(@"https://www." + site);
                panelBrowser1.Controls.Add(browser);
                browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
            return complete;
        }

        private void FormBrowser_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
        { 
            browser.Dispose();
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }

        private void FormBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var site in listOfSites) {
                    InitChromeBrowser(site);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The code is pretty simple enough, i'm passing through an array of the sites to display, and then loop them, the problem is only the first checked site is displayed, the `foreach` does not move to the next site (at least not in the browser) when i check via a `MsgBox` all sites are passed through fine. am i missing something simple? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked to see what is in the `panelBrowser1.Controls` collection? There should be a browser for each URL in that collection. Since you are setting `browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`, you can probably only see the first one.

Comment: Your code is going to be throwing an exception, you can Only call Cef.Initialize once per process. Move it outside of the loop. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown

Comment: Thank you guys, solved will update the code in a bit :)